# Python - get static information

Tags: python, variables, static

i have to get static information from one 'module' to another. I'm trying to write logger with information about code place from where we're logging.
For example, in some file:

```
LogObject.Log('Describe error', STATIC_INFORMATION)
```

Static information is class name, file name and function name.
I get it from this:

```
__file__ 
self.__class__.__name__ 
sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

But i don't want to write this variables during logging. Can i create some function and call it. For example:

```
LogObject.Log('Describe error', someFunction())
```

How can i use it for getting static information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think "static" is the world you're looking for. If I understand you correctly, you want to write a function that will return the filename, class name and method name of the caller.

Basically, you should use sys._getframe(1) to access the previous frame, and work from there.

Example:

```
def codeinfo():
    import sys
    f = sys._getframe(1)

    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    classname = ''

    if 'self' in f.f_locals:
        classname = f.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__

    funcname = f.f_code.co_name

    return "filename: %s\nclass: %s\nfunc: %s" % (filename, classname, funcname)
```

Then from a method somewhere you can write

```
logger.info("Some message \n %s" % codeinfo())
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about function name?

Comment: Added. This is not very good code, though. I'll try to clean it up when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

First, please use lower-case names for objects and methods.    Only use UpperCase Names for Class definitions.

More importantly, you want a clever introspective function in every class, it appears.

```
class Loggable( object ):
    def identification( self ):
        return self.__class__.__module__, self.__class__.__name__, sys._getframe().f_code.co_name

class ARealClass( Loggable ):
    def someFunction( self ):
        logger.info( "Some Message from %r", self. identification() )
```

If all of your classes are subclasses of Loggable, you'll inherit this identification function in all classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
>If all of your classes are subclasses of Loggable.
No, they aren't. If i'll create class Loggable in other module (file) the data which it returns will not be that what i need. Or i didn't understand?

Comment: Have you tried it?  If each class is a subclass of Loggable, each class will produce proper values for each object of the class.  It will work in multiple files.  Try it.

Comment: I shouldn't inherit all my classes from logger. I have another structure of my app.

Comment: That's what mixins are for. Your classes can inherit from more than one thing - so you can do class MyClass(Loggable, MySuperClass) and you will inherit both the loggable bits and your own stuff.

Comment: Or, replace `object` with `Loggable`.  If you aren't subclassing object, you should be.